# get_query_var returns null

Tags: wp-query

My pretty permalink clearly shows the query_var:

```
localhost/site/?tree=312
```

Yet when I run

```
var_dump(get_query_var('tree'));
```

I get NULL returned.

Any reason why? Also when I print_r($wp_query), I can't find 'tree' anywhere.

Comment: well first, that isn't a pretty permalink, it's a query string argument. what is tree? is it a registered query var?

Comment: @Milo - I'm elaborating on the url. It's more like localhost/site/category/?tree=312. I added the query_arg when I displayed the link: add_query_arg('tree',$post->ID,get_permalink($post->ID)); I'm basically passing the ID in the URL and I thought I'd give it a name of 'tree'.

Comment: I guess I'm suppose to register it, huh?

Comment: yes, see my answer.

Comment: ps. not 'elaborating' but the opposite of that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add any query vars that are not WordPress objects to the array of recognized query vars to be able to retrieve it from the `$wp_query` global:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa66452_query_vars' );
function wpa66452_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'tree';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Comment: Would it be more efficient to run global $wp; $wp >add_query_var('tree'); ?

Comment: no difference in efficiency, but the filter is the proper way to add them

Comment: Note: I had the same issue, add_filter fixed it but I also had to declare my $page variable below get_header()